# Is there any compression available in libcurl

Tags: c++, libcurl

I need to transfer a huge file from local machine to remote machine using libcurl with C++. Is there any compression option available in-built with libcurl. As the data to be transferred is large (100 MB to 1 GB in size), it would be better if we have any such options available in libcurl itself. I know we can compress the data and send it via libcurl. But just want to know is there any better way of doing so.

Note: In my case, many client machines transfer such huge data to remote server at regular interval of time.

thanks,
Prabu

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'll definitely work on this. So far I don't know what is that until your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [`curl_setopt()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) and options `CURLOPT_ENCODING`, you may specify:

> The contents of the "Accept-Encoding: " header. This enables decoding
>   of the response. Supported encodings are "identity", "deflate", and
>   **"gzip"**. If an empty string, "", is set, a header containing all
>   supported encoding types is sent.

[Here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) are some examples (just hit search in your browser and type in `compression`), but I don't know hot exactly does it work and whether it expect already gzipped data.

You still may use [`gzcompress()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzcompress.php) and send compressed chunks on your own (and I would do the task this way... you'll have better control on what's actually going on and you'll be able to change used algorithms).

Comment: This answer and the libcurl option is for _downloads_ though, and I got the impression the question was for _uploads_...

Comment: @DanielStenberg ah you're right...  Then just the last paragraph is the answer :-/

Answer (score 0):

You need to send your file with zlib compression by yourself. And perhaps there are some modification needed on the server-side.